# Is Java's awt KeyListener run on a separate thread or not?

Tags: java, multithreading, listener

In other words, is the Keylistener running synchronously or asynchronously to the main thread?

Comment: A Keylistener receives events in the UI thread, not your main thread.

Comment: I would not use the word, "running" here.  Your `KeyListener`'s methods are _called_ by the UI thread to notify your application about key press and release events. I personally would not use the word "running" unless something was _continually_ doing some task, over and over again in a loop.

Comment: You could always test this with [`EventQueue.isDispatchThread()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/EventQueue.html#isDispatchThread()) or, if using Swing, [`SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#isEventDispatchThread()) (which just forwards to `EventQueue` anyway).